# start load event for UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue

I want to animating activity indicator when tableView load the post after tapping on cell. So, when I tap on cell with the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        performSegueWithIdentifier("body", sender: nil)
}
```

First problem is on load the app this indicator already runs and visible. I did hide it with

```
loading.alpha = 0
```

and inside of didSelectedRow put:

```
loading.alpha = 1
loading.startAnimating()
```

but in this case it show it very late and shortly between the transition from A to B.

Can I make that it will show the loading while the segue(second) doesn't fully loaded yet, so before the transition process not only in table view but everywhere?

Comment: Have you tried showing it in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @Michal it asks me to return NSIndexPath. I just put inside it `loading.startAnimating()`

Comment: Just return the same you receive, you don't need to handle it, but show it and start animation there, rather then in `didSelect...`.

Comment: @Michal it doesn't work. Crashes the app

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: @Michal it cannot pass variables to the second segue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75372/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-michal).